# Taking riba to pay creditors for unused money.

Tags: halal-haram

Me and my friends, we were involved to a Cryptocurrency company for earning money. We invested our capital by giving him lacks of rupees, he lured us as giving much benefits than any other work and finally the company ran away.  Few of us lended the money, so my question is
Can we take the interest amount from those who leave thier amount in banks. Actually I am thinking if they take away our halal money so I can get back it from this method. What you say?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Islam SE is not a fatwa site. You should consider consulting a _mufti_ in your area. Please take a [tour] in our [help] and see [ask].